# I can no longer change the height and width of a text box when it's set for multiline

Tags: acumatica

Until I upgraded to 2020 R1 (20.102.0015), I had custom screens that used form text boxes (in either a header section or a grid's form view) with the style set to multiline - which made them expandable by grabbing the bottom right handle and expanding / contracting them to a desired size.  I had set MinHeight and MinWidth (or Width / Height), and that had no effect on the ability to expand the size of the box - it worked fine, and set the minimum size of the box on the first instantiation of the form.  Now, it's only expandable if I don't specify any Height or Width information.  Is this a new limitation placed on it by the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is related to CSS style in file '\App_Themes\Default\00_Controls.css':

```
textarea.editor.auto-size {
  resize: none;
}
```

To get resize handles you should style the control to have them because this style applies none by default.

You can add a new style at the bottom of '00_Controls.css' file:

```
.ResizeTextBox {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And assign it to controls which needs the resize handle to be visible:
[image]

Comment: The CSS class applied to the HTML control is determined by the ASPX control properties (autosize/width/height/etc..) but the behavior is not likely to be maintained between versions. Explicitly setting the desired style should ensure the solution won't break in future versions.

Comment: Beauty, Thanks Hugues!  ;D